# How to get the method of an endpoint from EndpointDispatcher

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

How can I match an EndpointDispatcher object to it's service method? I added attributes to my endpoint methods and now I want to add inspectors to only methods that have the attribute.

```
public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < serviceHostBase.ChannelDispatchers.Count; i++)
    {
        ChannelDispatcher channelDispatcher = serviceHostBase.ChannelDispatchers[i] as ChannelDispatcher;
        if (channelDispatcher != null)
        {
            foreach (EndpointDispatcher endpointDispatcher in channelDispatcher.Endpoints)
            {
                var methods = typeof(DataService).GetMethods();
                foreach (var method in methods)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine(method.Name);
                }
                endpointDispatcher.DispatchRuntime.MessageInspectors.Add(new HttpInspector());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you can't have operation-level message inspectors - they are always at least endpoint-level.
But what you can do is to apply filtering inside your message inspector based on the attribute you set on operations.
See example here: [Message logging with MessageInspector in Operation level](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/bcd94cf9-2881-4081-a05b-771a6e6f9c06/message-logging-with-messageinspector-in-operation-level?forum=wcf)